# .net mvc Entity framework primary key is null after Add to context for an identity property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

For a dbset which I have created

```
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Book Name")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd/MM/yy}")]
    [Display(Name ="Published date")]
    public DateTime? PublishedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Added To Library")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd/MM/yy}")]
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Books in Library")]
    public int NoOfCopies { get; set; }

    public Genere Genere { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Genere")]
    public byte GenereId { get; set; }
```

I then tried to create a new record and add it to dbcontext

```
     _context.Books.Add(book);
```

but getting the error `cannot add null to Id` which is the primary key when

```
      _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: did you use auto increment option?

Comment: nope i just try to set the id property as a identity property [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]                                     but it wont work then set it to [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]                          and set the Id value to random value                                                                                                                                                                                                        Random random = new Random();
book.Id = random.Next(1, 1000000);       then it works.

Comment: plz describe code of primary key

Comment: Thanks for the response, EF recognize the property of an entity which is having the naming convention Id or <ClassName>Id as the key of the entity

Comment: Maybe you can try with fluent api to override the default behavior.

Comment: maybe the problem is with book.Genere...  It would be nice to have the code you use to create the book to know for sure.

Comment: make sure that the field on your database is identity. Maybe there was a problem creating the table

Answer (score 0):

Add Key Attribute

```
[Key]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Id already is the primary key of entity Book, that doesn't works for me

Answer (score 0):

You must use Key Attribute or use Id convention after entity name "BookId"

Answer (score 0):

I manually update the table definition                                                                          `[Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,`
then problem solved id is increment automatically.